# How to create a new instance of Matplotlib Axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib, psse

I am using a power system simulation software called PSSE, which includes a module named `dyntools`, which is based on Matplotlib. I am trying to use Dyntools to plot each .OUT file in a directory, one by one (.OUT file is a PSSE file that contains data that `dyntools` can process).

What I am doing is setting up my `optnchn` dictionary (channel options: an attribute of `dyntools` class `chnf`, which tells what information from the .OUT file I want to plot). Then looping through each .OUT file in the directory, creating a `chnf` object, updating the filename, and calling `chnf` function `xyplots` to plot it.  This works fine, in the sense that I get a pdf file output for each .OUT file, but I get the following error:

`C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py:107: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Adding an axes using the same arguments as a previous axes currently reuses the earlier instance.  In a future version, a new instance will always be created and returned.  Meanwhile, this warning can be suppressed, and the future behavior ensured, by passing a unique label to each axes instance.`

What ends up happening is that each subsequent file has the correct data plotted from its .OUT file, but the header at the top of the file overlaps the previous file.  Dyntools applies a header to the PDF files that contain the  .OUT file path, among other information. This becomes an unreadable mess because it keeps writing the new header over the previous file's header. Any ideas as to how I can overcome this?

Notes on the code:

- PSSE assigns an error code to the variable `ierr`, which computes to `True` if an error was found, `False` if no error. This always computes to `False` in this code

```
    # Create list with all .OUT files in directory
    outlist = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\Manny\Documents\PRC-12\2019_Snf_RAS_Effectiveness\results\dynamics\Phase_I\_OUT\*.out')

    # Setup Channels
    optnchn = {1:{'chns':[7,9,53,55,59,79]},
                2:{'chns':[15,25,37,39,71,73]},
                3:{'chns':[17,43,47,57,65,75]},
                4:{'chns':[92,93,95,96,107,115]},
                5:{'chns':[98,102,104,111,112,114]},
                6:{'chns': [100,103,105,109,119,120]},
                7:{'chns': [81,83,85,86,88,89]}
                }

    # Counter for filenames
    j = 1

    # Loop thru each .OUT file
    for i in outlist:

        # Create object with current out file, set options
        chnf = dyntools.CHNF(i)
        optn = {'size': 'Letter', 'orientation': 'Landscape', 'title': 'SNF RAS - Phase I', 'dpi': 300, 'showttl': True}

        # Set Filename for current .OUT file plot results
        plotfile1 = r'C:\Users\Manny\Documents\PRC-12\2019_Snf_RAS_Effectiveness\results\plot_logs\PHASE I\SimPlots'
        plotfile2 = j
        plotfile3 = '.pdf'
        plotfile = plotfile1 + str(plotfile2) + plotfile3
        j = j+1

        # Produce Plot
        ierr = chnf.xyplots(optnchn, optn, plotfile)

        if ierr:
            print('Errors Were Found')

        else:
            print('No Errors Found')
```

Update: Below is the `chnf` portion of the `dyntools` documentation from PSSE:

```
CLASSES
    CHNF
    OUTDATA

    class CHNF
     |  This class reads PSSE dynamics simulation studies channel output binary (.out) files, and
     |  provides methods to access and post process the data from those files.
     |  
     |  Methods defined here:
     |  
     |  __init__(self, *outfiles, **kwds)
     |      Create CHNF object as below and apply various methods defined here.
     |      
     |      Syntax:
     |          chnfobj = dyntools.CHNF(*outfiles, **kwds)
     |      
     |      Arguments:
     |          outfiles = Provide one or more PSSE dynamics channel output file names separated by comma.
     |                     At least one file name must be provided.
     |      Allowed Keywords:
     |          outvrsn  = 0, for no Extended Channel output file type (.out)
     |                   = 1, for Extended Channel output file type (.outx) (default)
     |  
     |  csvout(self, channels='', csvfile='', outfile='', ntimestep=1)
     |      Write PSSE Dynamic Simulation Channel Output File Data to ASCII text file.
     |      chnfobj.csvout(outfile, channels, csvfile, ntimestep)
     |      channels = Channel numbers to extract, specified as a channel number or
     |                 list of channel numbers to extract.
     |                 If not specified, all channels are extracted, default.
     |      csvfile  = Data saved to this Text File
     |                 Default extension - .csv
     |                 Default name - outfile name with .csv extension
     |      outfile  = PSSE Dynamic Simulation Channel Output File Name (.out), when not
     |                 provided, used 1st file from the files provided during object creation.
     |      ntimestep= Number of timesteps per data export, i.e., for every 'ntimestep' data
     |                 is exported. Default=1, i.e., export data for every time step.
     |  
     |  get_data(self, channels='', outfile='')
     |      Return short_title, chanid and chandata for outfile.
     |      short_title, chanid, chandata = chnfobj.get_data(channels,outfile)
     |      channels    = Channel numbers to extract, specified as a channel number or
     |                    list of channel numbers to extract.
     |                    If not specified, all channels are extracted, default.
     |      outfile     = PSSE Dynamic Simulation Channel Output File Name (.out), when not
     |                    provided, used 1st file from the files provided during object creation.
     |      Returns
     |      short_title = String of Short title of the PSSE case
     |      chanid      = Dictionary of Channel IDs, {'time':'Time(s)',1:id1,2:id2,...,n:idn}
     |      chandata    = Dictionary of Channel Data, {'time':[v],1:[v1],2:[v2],...,n:[vn]}
     |                    where 1, 2, ..n are channel numbers available in the input file
     |                          id1, id2, ...idn are the channel identifiers.
     |                          v, v1, v2, ...vn are data values.
     |  
     |  get_id(self, outfile='')
     |      Return short_title and chanid for outfile.
     |      short_title, chanid = chnfobj.get_id(outfile)
     |      outfile     = PSSE Dynamic Simulation Channel Output File Name (.out), when not
     |                    provided, used 1st file from the files provided during object creation.
     |      Returns
     |      short_title = String of Short title of the PSSE case
     |      chanid      = Dictionary of Channel IDs, {'time':'Time(s)',1:id1,2:id2,...,n:idn}
     |  
     |  get_range(self, outfile='')
     |      Return actual minimum and maximum channel values (range) for outfile.
     |      chanrange = chnfobj.get_range(outfile)
     |      outfile   = PSSE Dynamic Simulation Channel Output File Name (.out), when not
     |                  provided, used 1st file from the files provided during object creation.
     |      Returns
     |      chanrange = Dictionary of Channel range values
     |                = {'time':{'min':v,'max':v},
     |                       1 :{'min':v,'max':v},......
     |                       n :{'min':v,'max':v} }
     |                  where 1, 2, ..n are channel numbers available in the outfile
     |                        'min':v are minumum values, and 'max':v maximum values.
     |  
     |  get_scale(self, outfile='')
     |      Return scaled (for plots) minimum and maximum channel values for outfile.
     |      chanscale = chnfobj.get_scale(outfile)
     |      outfile   = PSSE Dynamic Simulation Channel Output File Name (.out), when not
     |                  provided, used 1st file from the files provided during object creation.
     |      Returns
     |      chanscale = Dictionary of Channel range values
     |                = {'time':{'min':v,'max':v},
     |                       1 :{'min':v,'max':v},......
     |                       n :{'min':v,'max':v} }
     |                  where 1, 2, ..n are channel numbers available in the outfile
     |                        'min':v are minumum values, and 'max':v maximum values.
     |  
     |  plots_close(self)
     |      Close created plots.
     |  
     |  plots_show(self)
     |      Show created plots.
     |  
     |  print_scale(self, outfile='')
     |      Print actuval range and scaled (for plots) minimum and maximum channel values for outfile.
     |      outfile = PSSE Dynamic Simulation Channel Output File Name (.out), when not
     |                provided, used 1st file from the files provided during object creation.
     |  
     |  set_plot_legend_options(self, loc='upper right', borderpad=0.2, labelspacing=0.5, handlelength=1.5, handletextpad=0.5, fontsize=8, frame=False)
     |      Set plot legend options.
     |      where:
     |      loc           -> Any valid matplotlib legend location string, default='upper right'
     |                       Allowed: 'upper right', 'upper left', 'lower left', 'lower right',
     |                       'right', 'center left', 'center right', 'lower center', 'upper center',
     |                       'center'
     |      borderpad     -> Whitespace inside the legend border, default=0.2
     |      labelspacing  -> Vertical space between the legend entries, default=0.5
     |      handlelength  -> Length of the legend handles, default=1.5
     |      handletextpad -> Pad between the legend handle and text, default=0.5
     |      fontsize      -> Font size, default=8
     |      frame         -> Frame legend box or not, default False
     |      Note: The pad and spacing parameters are measured in font-size units.
     |            A fontsize of 10 points and a handlelength=5 implies a handlelength of 50 points.
     |  
     |  set_plot_line_colors(self, *args)
     |      Set plot line colors.
     |      where:
     |      args is one or more plot line colors allowed by matplotlib.
     |      Following are some of the allowed colors names:
     |          'blue', 'red', 'black', 'green', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'darkblue', 'beige',
     |          'brown', 'gray', 'khaki', 'pink', 'purple', 'royalblue', 'violet'
     |  
     |  set_plot_line_styles(self, *args)
     |      Set plot line styles.
     |      where:
     |      args is one or more plot line styles allowed by matplotlib.
     |      Allowed matplotlib plot line styles are:
     |          'solid', 'dashed', 'dashdot', 'dotted'
     |  
     |  set_plot_markers(self, *args)
     |      Set plot markers.
     |      where:
     |      args is one or more plot markers allowed by matplotlib.
     |      Allowed matplotlib markers are:
     |          'square', 'triangle_up', 'thin_diamond', 'plus', 'x', 'circle', 'star', 'hexagon1',
     |          'pentagon', 'tri_down', 'tri_up', 'tri_left', 'tri_right', 'triangle_left',
     |          'triangle_right', 'triangle_down', 'diamond', 'octagon'
     |  
     |  set_plot_page_options(self, size='Letter', orientation='Portrait')
     |      Set plot page options.
     |      where:
     |      size        -> paper size, default 'Letter',
     |                     Allowed: 'Letter', 'Legal', 'A3', 'A4',
     |      orientation -> page orientation, default 'Portrait',
     |                     Allowed: 'Portrait', 'Landscape'
     |  
     |  txtout(self, channels='', txtfile='', outfile='', ntimestep=1)
     |      Write PSSE Dynamic Simulation Channel Output File Data to ASCII text file.
     |      chnfobj.txtout(outfile, channels, txtfile, ntimestep)
     |      channels = Channel numbers to extract, specified as a channel number or
     |                 list of channel numbers to extract.
     |                 If not specified, all channels are extracted, default.
     |      txtfile  = Data saved to this Text File
     |                 Default extension - .txt
     |                 Default name - outfile name with .txt extension
     |      outfile  = PSSE Dynamic Simulation Channel Output File Name (.out), when not
     |                 provided, used 1st file from the files provided during object creation.
     |      ntimestep= Number of timesteps per data export, i.e., for every 'ntimestep' data
     |                 is exported. Default=1, i.e., export data for every time step.
     |  
     |  xlsout(self, channels='', show=True, xlsfile='', outfile='', sheet='', overwritesheet=True, ntimestep=1)
     |      Export PSSE Dynamic Simulation Channel Output File Data to Excel Spreadsheet.
     |      
     |      xlsout() function require Python Win32 Extensions 'pywin32' module.
     |      Self installation EXE files for this module is available at:
     |           PSSE User Support Web Page and follow link 'Python Modules used by PSSE Python Utilities'.
     |      Install it if already not installed.
     |      
     |      xlsfile  = chnfobj.xlsout(outfile,channels,show,xlsfile)
     |      channels = Channel numbers to extract, specified as a channel number or
     |                 list of channel numbers to extract.
     |                 If not specified, all channels are extracted, default.
     |      show     = True (default) - Show Excel Spreadsheet when being populated,
     |               = False - Hide
     |      xlsfile  = Data saved to this Excel File, with or without extension.
     |                 When no extension provided, extension - .xls  (Office 2003 and earlier) or
     |                                                         .xlsx (Office 2007 and later)
     |                 Default name - outfile name with .xls/.xlsx extension
     |      outfile  = PSSE Dynamic Simulation Channel Output File Name (.out), when not
     |                 provided, used 1st file from the files provided during object creation.
     |      sheet    = Excel worksheet name, default ''
     |      overwritesheet: Overwrite worksheets flag, default True
     |                    = True,  existing worksheets are overwritten
     |                    = False, existing worksheets are copied and their names
     |                      appended with (#), where # is next sequence number.
     |      ntimestep= Number of timesteps per data export, i.e., for every 'ntimestep' data
     |                 is exported. Default=1, i.e., export data for every time step.
     |  
     |  xyplots(self, optnchn={}, optnfmt={'addmarker': True, 'columns': 1, 'dpi': 300, 'legendtype': 1, 'rows': 1, 'showlogo': False, 'showoutfnam': True, 'showttl': True}, plotsavfile='')
     |      Do XY plots.
     |      
     |      xyplots() function require matplotlib and numpy modules.
     |      Self installation EXE files for these modules are available at:
     |           PSSE User Support Web Page and follow link 'Python Modules used by PSSE Python Utilities'.
     |      Install these modules if already not installed.
     |      
     |      retvfiles = chnfobj.xyplots(optnchn,optnfmt,plotsavfile)
     |      
     |      optnchn = Is a dictionary specifying channels to plot and plotting options
     |              = { 1 : {'chns'  : ch# or [ch1, ch2, ..] or {fnam:ch#} or {fnam:[ch1, chn2, ..]} or
     |                                 [ch#, 'vf'] or [ch1, 'vf1', ch2, 'vf2', ch3, ch4, 'vf4'] or
     |                                 [ch1, ch2, 'vf2', ch3, ch4, 'vf4'] or
     |                                 {fnam: [ch1, 'vf1', ch2, 'vf2', ch3, ch4, 'vf4', ...]}
     |                                 where 'vf' is any valid Python expression (valid function)
     |                                 that modifes immediate preceding channel data.
     |                                 (See Note 2)
     |                       'title' : '',
     |                       'ylabel': '',
     |                       'xlabel': '',
     |                       'xscale': [min, max],
     |                       'yscale': [min, max],
     |                       'xaxis' : ch# or {fnam:ch#} or [ch#, 'vf'] or {fnam:[ch#, 'vf']}
     |                      },
     |                  n : { .... } }
     |                where,
     |                --> 1 to n are figure numbers.
     |      
     |                Note 1: When output file name is not provided while specifying X or Y channels,
     |                        1st file provided during object creation is used.
     |      
     |                For each figure, specify following
     |                --> 'chns' are Y-axis channels numbers.
     |                    When Y-axis channel file is 1st .out file, specify it as ch# or as list [ch#,ch#..]
     |                    When Y-axis channels are from multiple .out files or not 1st .out file,
     |                         specify as dictionary. For example:
     |                         'chns':{fnam1:ch#, fnam2:[ch#,ch#], ...}
     |                    When channels from multiple files are to be plotted in particular file order,
     |                         specify them as OrderedDict. For example:
     |                         'chns':collections.OrderedDict([(fnam1,ch#), (fnam2,ch#), (fnam3,ch#), ..)])
     |      
     |                --> 'title'  is Figure Title, default None
     |                --> 'ylabel' is Figure Y axis label, default None
     |                --> 'xlabel' is Figure X axis label, default 'Time (s)'
     |                --> 'yscale' is the list of two values of ymin and ymax, default Channel min and max
     |                --> 'xscale' is the list of two values of xmin and xmax, default Channel min and max
     |                --> 'xaxis'  is the X-axis channel number, default Time axis from .out file
     |      
     |                Note 2:
     |                'vf' is any valid function/expression that can be evaluated with eval(..) in Python.
     |                     Use 'v0' as variable name of 1st value in channel data,
     |                     Use 'v'  as variable name of each time step value in channel data
     |      
     |                 'vf' operation is applied to only one preceding channel number in 'chns' list.
     |                 Example: chns = [ch1, 'vf1', ch2, 'vf2', ch3, ch4, 'vf4']
     |                 In this,
     |                 a) channel data modified by 'vf' operation: ch1 by 'vf1', ch2 by 'vf2', and ch4 by 'vf4'.
     |                 b) channel data ch3 is not modified by any operation.
     |      
     |                 Examples of valid 'vf' specification:
     |                 a) Convert pu frequency to frequency on 60 Hz base
     |                        vf = '(1+v)*60'
     |                 b) Convert channel data to pu data based on v0
     |                        vf = 'v/v0'
     |                 c) Scale channel data by any factor, like converting pu Power to MW power when sbase=100
     |                        vf = 'v*100.0'
     |      
     |                 Test if 'vf' is valid as below (from any Python interpreter):
     |                 >>> v0=1.0
     |                 >>> v=1.0
     |                 >>> vf = '(1+v)*60'
     |                 >>> eval(vf)
     |                 >>> vf = 'v/v0'
     |                 >>> eval(vf)
     |      
     |      optnfmt = Is a dictionary specifying figure format options
     |              = { 'rows'       : 1,
     |                  'columns'    : 1,
     |                  'dpi'        : 300,
     |                  'showttl'    : True,
     |                  'showoutfnam': True,
     |                  'showlogo'   : True,
     |                  'legendtype' : 1,
     |                  'addmarker'  : True,
     |                }
     |                where
     |                --> 'rows' is a number of rows in a figure, default 1
     |                --> 'columns' is a number of columns in a figure, default 1
     |                    'rows' and 'columns' determine number of subplots in a figure
     |                --> 'dpi' plot file resolution dots per inch, default 300
     |      
     |                Use following to format Figure title.
     |                --> 'showttl' show Short Title from .out file or not, default True
     |                --> 'showoutfnam' show .out file names or not, default True
     |                --> 'showlogo' show PTI plot logo, default True
     |      
     |                Use 'legendtype' to format individual plot legend, default 1.
     |                --> 'legendtype' : 0, no legend
     |                    Note: Here (A), #5, ANG1MINE are used for illustration only. Actual file order will
     |                          depend on CHNF object, channel number and its title will be taken from .out file.
     |                --> 'legendtype' : 1 to Legend or plot title will be formatted as: CHNL File (A), #5: ANG1MINE
     |                                 : 2 to Legend or plot title will be formatted as: (A)(5): ANG1MINE
     |                                 : 3 to Legend or plot title will be formatted as: (5): ANG1MINE
     |                                 : 4 to Legend or plot title will be formatted as: ANG1MINE
     |                Note: Legends can be dragged and placed at different location. If done so, use 'Save the figure'
     |                      button in Figure Window to save the modified figure.
     |      
     |                --> 'addmarker': Draw plots with markers added or not, default True
     |      
     |      plotsavfile = Is a file name to save plots to, default None
     |                    allowed file extensions - '.eps','.png','.pdf','.ps'
     |                    Saved plot file type determined from extension, default extension 'png'
     |                    When plots require more than one page, multipage pdf file is created when selected.
     |                    For other file formats, file names are appended with 1,2,3..n.
     |                    When plot file exists, it will be overwritten.
     |      Returns
     |      retvfiles   = Is a list of file names where plots are saved.
     |  
     |  xyplots2doc(self, optnchn, optnfmt={}, docfile='', show=True, overwrite=False, caption=True, align='center', captionpos='below', height=0.0, width=0.0, rotate=0.0)
     |      Do XY plots and insert them in a Word Document.
     |      
     |      NOTE: When using this function, need to run python script which uses this function
     |      from any Python interpreter (outside of PSSE GUI). It will not work when
     |      called from PSSE GUI.
     |      
     |      xyplots2doc() function require matplotlib, numpy and pywin32 modules.
     |      Self installation EXE files for these modules are available at:
     |           PSSE User Support Web Page and follow link 'Python Modules used by PSSE Python Utilities'.
     |      Install these modules if already not installed.
     |      
     |      ierr, docfile = chnfobj.xyplots2doc(optnchn,optnfmt,show,xlsfile)
     |      optnchn    = Channels to plot
     |      optnfmt    = Figure format options
     |          Refer xyplots() funtion for details on optnchn and optnfmt.
     |      docfile    = Plots inserted into this Word Document File
     |                   Default extension - .doc
     |                   Default name - Document# with .doc extension
     |      show       = True (default) - Show Word document when being populated,
     |                 = False - Hide
     |      overwrite  = True, overwrite if file exists, file contents will be deleted.
     |                 = False (default), do not overwrite if file exists, plots inserted at the end.
     |      caption    = Figure caption
     |                 = True (default), Only "Figure #" is used as caption
     |                 = False, no caption
     |      align      = Alignment, default - 'center', allowed: 'center','left','right','justify'
     |      captionpos = Position of figure caption, default - 'below', allowed: 'below', 'above'
     |      height     = Height in inches, default - original figure height
     |      width      = Width  in inches, default - original figure width
     |      rotate     = Clockwise rotation angle in degrees, default 0.0
     |      Returns
     |      ierr       = True, Successfully inserted plots in Word document
     |                 = False, xyplots() function did not produce plots, hence plots are not inserted Word document
     |      docfile    = Name of the DOC file created
```

Comment: Seems `PSSE/dyntools` is closed source? In that case it's pretty hard to know what's going on. But they have a help forum https://psspy.org/psse-help-forum/questions/ which might be better suited.

Comment: PSSE is closed source.  If it helps, I have edited the question to add the portion of the documentation that covers the `chnf`  class.  I have tried to use psspy.org, but the forum seems to be having issues with the sign-up process.

Comment: Unfortunately the docstring isn't that helpful. You could try to put a `plt.figure()` inside the loop before creating the plot via `.xyplots` to see if that function makes use of pyplot and its current axes.

Comment: Unfortunately inserting a `plt.figure()` before creating the plot resulted in the same outcome.  I did try to use the `.plots_close` function after the plot has been created.  This seems to just break out of the loop and terminate the program.  I also tried moving the `.xyplots` call to its own function, then saying `return (chnf)`, hoping that this would somehow "close" that instance of `chnf`.  All of these attempts resulted in the same outcome of the plot header overlapping the previous file's header.

Comment: I suspect that this program is just having a bug or unfortunate choice of using matplotlib. As it's closed source one cannot find out or help fixing it. Consider plotting the data externally, for which you can get help here.

Comment: Thank you for all your help.  My solution was to set `showoutfnam` to `False` in the `.xyplots` options.  This prevents dyntools from automatically applying the .OUT file title to the header.  Then, I added the `optnchn` dictionary to the loop, and put a `title = str(i)` at the top of each loop iteration, and used the `'title'` attribute of the `optnchn` dictionary to change the title each iteration.  This essentially got around an apparent bug with the `.xyplots` function.

Comment: If you think this solution would be useful for someone in the future, consider providing it as answer.

Comment: Actually, I'm back to square one.  It initially seemed like only the title in the header was being overlapped because I kept stopping after 3-5 plots and the data was similar between the .OUT files.  After plotting 100+ iterations, it became clear that each subsequent plot was overlapping the previous plot.  This seems to happen any time `.xyplots` is called more than once within the same process.  I'm currently investigating using a `subprocess` to iterate through .OUT files, and do something like `subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'abc.py', 'argument1', 'argument2'])`  to produce each plot.

Comment: Have you considered not using `chnf.xyplots()`?  You can use `chnf.get_data()` to get the raw data and then use `matplotlib` to get your plots exactly how you want.